# Input Automation to Shortest Path Algorithm (BFS Algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, data-science, breadth-first-search

I am using BFS Algorithm to find the shortest path between the points which covers all the points and generates the shortest path. I am giving input(nearest neighbors) manually, and finding difficulty in automating the input to BFS Algorithm. Also please suggest if you know any algorithm which does a better job to generate the shortest path covering all the points.

**Example:** Points - `[R59C36,R59C39,R59C52,R60C1,R60C20,R60C34,R62C2,R62C7,R63C8,R65C9,R66C11,R66C6,R67C11]`

**Input** – Giving nearest neighbors to each point

```
graph = {
    'R59C36':['R59C39','R59C52','R60C34','R60C20','R60C1'],
    'R59C39':['R59C52','R60C34','R60C20','R60C1'],
    'R60C1':['R60C20','R62C2','R62C7'],
    'R60C20':['R60C34','R62C2','R62C7'],
    'R60C34':['R62C2','R62C7'],
    'R59C52':['R60C34'],
    'R62C2':['R62C7','R63C8'],
    'R62C7':['R63C8'],
    'R63C8':['R65C9'],
    'R65C9':['R66C6','R66C11'],
    'R66C6':['R66C11','R67C11'],
    'R66C11':['R67C11'],
    'R67C11':[]
}
```

**Output** - `R59C36, R59C39, R59C52, R60C34, R60C20, R60C1, R62C2, R62C7, R63C8, R65C9, R66C6, R66C11, R67C11`

Comment: A shortest path algorithm that covers all the points can solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem, which is NP complete. Therefore you are unlikely to find an efficient algorithm for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
graph = {
    'R59C36':['R59C39','R59C52','R60C34','R60C20','R60C1'],
    'R59C39':['R59C52','R60C34','R60C20','R60C1'],
    'R60C1':['R60C20','R62C2','R62C7'],
    'R60C20':['R60C34','R62C2','R62C7'],
    'R60C34':['R62C2','R62C7'],
    'R59C52':['R60C34'],
    'R62C2':['R62C7','R63C8'],
    'R62C7':['R63C8'],
    'R63C8':['R65C9'],
    'R65C9':['R66C6','R66C11'],
    'R66C6':['R66C11','R67C11'],
    'R66C11':['R67C11'],
    'R67C11':[]
}
points = ['R59C36','R59C39','R59C52','R60C1','R60C20','R60C34','R62C2','R62C7','R63C8','R65C9','R66C11','R66C6','R67C11']


output = []
for point in points:
    if point not in output:
        output.append(point)
    
    _points = graph[point]
    for _point in _points:
        if _point not in output:
            output.append(_point)

print(output)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I have code (BFS Algorithm) to generate the output. I have to automate the input (graph - automatically assigning nearest neighbors to each point from the list of given points). Now I am assigning nearest neighbors to each point manually, I have to automate this.